# JQuery.cookies library

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm trying to use the JQuery cookies library http://code.google.com/p/cookies/
But am not able to set key value pairs within the cookie. I can't see how in the documentation, does anyone know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
$.cookies.set( 'sessid', 'dh3tr62fghe' );
```

So, in this case **sessid** is your key, **dh3tr62fghe** is value.

If this is not what did you ask, sorry then.

Comment: I don't think that does it! It creates a cookie called sessid and a value of dh3tr62fghe as per the docementation.